# What is "?." when accessing object property in JS (typescript?)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have found this piece of code in on example:

```
const value: Token | undefined = object?.token
```

What this part "**object?.token**" actually means?

I cannot find it online, I am not sure how to search for it.

I understand that `object.token` is used to access token property of object, but what is the use of "?"

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is called `Optional Chaining` in Typescript.

> Optional chaining lets us write code where TypeScript can immediately stop running some expressions if we run into a null or undefined.

For your example if object is not `null` and `undefined` get the value of property `token`.

See [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html)